# Hanging in Multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing.Queue to split a file into several smaller files. While the code below works often, sometimes it will hang on :

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pedroq/miniconda3/envs/drax_annot/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 265, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/home/pedroq/miniconda3/envs/drax_annot/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 189, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pedroq/miniconda3/envs/drax_annot/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 192, in _finalize_join
    thread.join()
  File "/home/pedroq/miniconda3/envs/drax_annot/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1032, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/home/pedroq/miniconda3/envs/drax_annot/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1048, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm not sure why? The data being passed to the processes can be quite large, could this be an issue? Here is the pseudocode I'm using:

```
def generate_split_processes_to_run(self,protein_seqs,seq_chunks):
    c=0
    for chunk in seq_chunks:
        self.queue.put([protein_seqs,chunk,c])
        c+=1

def sample_split_handler(self,protein_seqs,protein_seqs_groups,worker_count):
    #loading the queue
    self.generate_split_processes_to_run(protein_seqs,protein_seqs_groups)
    #spawning the processes
    processes = [Process(target=self.sample_split_worker, args=(self.queue,)) for _ in range(worker_count)]
    #starting the processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    #joining processes
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
        print(processes)


def sample_split_worker(self, queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        seqs, chunk, chunk_number= queue.get()
        self.save_chunks(seqs, chunk, chunk_number)

def split_sample(self):
    seqs=self.read_file(self.target_path)
    seqs_keys=list(seqs.keys())
    worker_count= 7
    seq_chunks= chunk_generator(seqs_keys, 1000)
    self.sample_split_handler(seqs,seq_chunks,worker_count)

def save_chunks(self,seqs,
                      chunk,
                      chunk_number):
    with open(chunk_path, 'w+') as file:
        while chunk:
            seq_id = chunk.pop(0)
            chunk_str = 'something'
            file.write('>' + seq_id + '\n' + chunk_str + '\n')
```

When I print the list of processes, they all appear to be finished:

```
[<Process(Process-1, stopped)>, <Process(Process-2, stopped)>, <Process(Process-3, stopped)>, <Process(Process-4, stopped)>, <Process(Process-5, stopped)>, <Process(Process-6, stopped)>, <Process(Process-7, stopped)>]
```

I used Pool before which worked fine but I'd like to use Queue now.
Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently this is a somewhat "common" issue.
Checking queue size with `.empty()` or `.qsize()` doesn't guarantee that the queue is truly empty. In fast processes you can often get a `queue.empty()==True` even thought the queue is not empty.

There are some proposed solutions for this:
1- Include a timer `sleep()` between processes so that the queue has time to get new items.
2- Add a sentinel to the queue.

The sentinel will guarantee that you always finish the queue, unlike the timer option.
After inserting items into your queue add a sentinel, like so `queue.put(None)` (`None` for low memory consumption). Insert a `None` for each process you are running.
This will result in something like this:

```
def sample_split_worker(self, queue):
    while True:
        #when the queue is finished, each process will receive a None, thus breaking the cycle.
        record = queue.get()
        If not record: break
        seqs, chunk, chunk_number = record
        self.save_chunks(seqs, chunk, chunk_number)
```

Hope this helps someone.